# Position eigenstates in curved space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, qft-in-curved-spacetime

How does one define position eigenstates in curved space (say a manifold $\mathcal{M}$)? Let us say that it is defined as usual $$\hat{x}|x\rangle = x|x\rangle$$ Then how does one define the identity operator in this basis? Is this proposal correct ? $$\int_{\mathcal{M}} d^4x~\sqrt{g}|x\rangle\langle x| = \bf{I}$$
where $g$ is the metric on $\mathcal{M}$. Can anyone provide appropriate reference in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a question of how to *normalize* the eigenstates. This is just a convention that can choose. Myself, I like to write $\langle x|x'\rangle= \delta_g^n(x-x')$ where the delta function is defined by
$$
\int_M d^nx \sqrt{g} \,\delta^n_g(x-x')=1,
$$
but other choices may be preferable.

What *is* important that you state your normalization conventions somwhere when attempting to communicate with others.

Comment: Since the question requested a reference: The fact that it's just a matter of convention is stated explicitly in Bastianelli and van Nieuwenhuizen's *Path integrals and anomalies in curved space* (section 2.1, page 25, text following equation 2.1.4).

Comment: @mike stone Thank you for your explanation. Can you also explain what happens if I did $Tr(\Omega(\hat{x})) = \int d^4x \sqrt{g}~Tr(\langle x|\Omega(\hat{x})|x \rangle)$ where $\Omega$ is a top-form on the manifold? I have simply inserted the identity in the RHS.